# Interrupting scanner depends on other thread

Tags: java, multithreading

The following working example prints every 3sec a integer between 1 and 20. The program should terminate if one of the two status flacs (t1.getStatus, t2.getStatus) are true. If `t1.getStatus`  is true then the program is still running, because the scanner doesn't terminate.

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FirstTask t1 = new FirstTask();

        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(t1, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        ParallelScanner t2 = new ParallelScanner();
        Thread scan = new Thread(t2);
        scan.start();

        while(true){
            if(t1.getStatus() || t2.getStatus()) break;
        }
        scan.interrupt();
        executor.shutdown();
    }

}

class ParallelScanner implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean status=false;

    public void run() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("scanner stoped");
        scan.close();
        this.status=true;
    }

    public boolean getStatus(){
        return this.status;
    }

}

class FirstTask implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean status=false;

    public void run() {
        this.status = status();
    }

    private boolean status() {
        int incident = (int) ((Math.random()*20)+1);
        System.out.println(incident);
        return incident < 7 ? true : false;
    }

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

}
```

To control the interrupt via status flac could be also the wrong scratch. I also found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803151/how-to-interrupt-a-scanner-nextline-call). Till now the first answer doesn't grab me. And the second answer is wrong. Could someone provide a small working example on this approach? Are there some other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know that your FirstTask only ever runs once, so that's ok.

You need to make your status variable `volatile` to have it read from ram by every thread, or you will get kinda undefined behaviour.

Why do you have no loop that uses the scanner? I do not know the specifics of your Scanner class, is there an exception thrown when there is no more data, or null returned as my code assumes?

```
for(;;){
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    if(input == null)
         break;
    // Assuming that by jump over (run through) you mean:
    // ignore the line that comes from the scanner
    if(!t1.getStatus()){
        System.out.println(input); 
    }
}
```

also your getStatus() method needs to reset the status to `true` or it will also ignore (= not print) all consecutive lines.

Comment: Thx for the keyword volatile. I rearranged the code and hopes that makes my question more understandable, because the issue is still the same. It prints every 3sec a number between 1-20. This is done by the executor. And the scanner is wrapped in a separate thread. But if the `t1.getStatus` is now true, the program is not terminated although the endless loop breaks. Because the scanner is waiting for input.