# error message : stream closed

Tags: java, error-handling, bufferedreader, ioexception

Upon running following code under class `FlightSearch`

```
String moreSearch = "y";
    List<Flight> resultList;

    // load initial flight data into DB
    if (!init()) {
        return;
    }
    // A background thread to monitor changes in csv repository
    FileListner fl = new FileListner();
    fl.start();

    do {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        // main thread gets input
        Input inputQuery = new Input();
        try {
            inputQuery.getQuery();
        } catch (InvalidException e1) {
            e1.getMessage();
        } finally {
            fl.stopThread();
        }
        // main thread STARTs processing task as background monitors csv
        // repo
        QueryProcessor processor = new QueryProcessor();
        resultList = null;
        resultList = processor.matchQuery(inputQuery);

        displayResult(resultList, inputQuery.getFlightClass());

        System.out
                .println("More Flight Query ? Press n/N to exit. Anyother key to continue searching.");

        try {
            moreSearch = br.readLine(); // LINE 56
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(br!=null){
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    } while (!moreSearch.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));

    System.out.println("Thank You !!!");
```

I get following error :

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at com.myApp.FlightSearch.main(FlightSearch.java:56)
```

I have also tried moving

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

moving out of do-while loop but in vain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The problem

The problem is that you execute the `br.close()` that, as javadoc states, closes the stream **and releases any system resources associated with it**.

Just for a quick verification comment out the:

```
if (br != null) {
//    try {
//        br.close();
//    } catch (IOException e) {
//        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//        e.printStackTrace();
//    }
}
```

and you can answer `s` any times you want without any exception.

### A solution

A solution is closing the buffer reader after all reads are terminated:

```
    String moreSearch = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    try {
        do {
            // ...
            System.out.println("More Flight Query ? Press n/N to exit. Anyother key to continue searching.");
            moreSearch = br.readLine();
        } while (!moreSearch.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(FlightSearch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Cant read line from a System.in based BufferedReader", e);
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException ignoreMe) {
                Logger.getLogger(FlightSearch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Can't close a System.in based BufferedReader", ignoreMe);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @KunalKrishna If you cut and paste my solution in a ```public static void main(String[] args) {...}``` it run without exception. Because my solution differs from your code only for the code omitted by ```// ...``` check in the omitted code if there is something that could close System.in. Or if you prefer paste some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're calling `br.close()` in the `finally` block where you read a line from the buffer. When you close a `Stream`, any stream that was wrapped by the one you closed is also closed. As a result, your first iteration through the `do { } while ()` loop is closing the `System.in InputStream`, which you cannot then reopen.

To avoid this, you can use a `CloseShieldInputStream` from Apache Commons to wrap `System.in` before you wrap it with the `InputStreamReader`. This will allow you to close the `BufferedReader` (which will also close the `InputStreamReader` and the `CloseShieldInputStream`) without triggering the closure of `System.in`.

See bmargulies answer here: [Closing BufferedReader and System.in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203981/closing-bufferedreader-and-system-in)

Answer (score 0):

After making changes as suggested in [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22612897/1851302) my code didn't tun but with slight more changes as shown below, my code compiled and run just fine

```
    try {
        do {
            // main thread gets input
            Input inputQuery = new Input();
            inputQuery.getQuery();

            // main thread STARTs processing task as background monitors csv
            // repo
            QueryProcessor processor = new QueryProcessor();
            resultList = null;
            resultList = processor.matchQuery(inputQuery);

            displayResult(resultList, inputQuery.getFlightClass());
            System.out
                    .println("More Flight Query ? Press n/N to exit. Anyother key to continue searching.");
            moreSearch = br.readLine();

        } while (!moreSearch.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidException e1) {
        e1.getMessage();
    } finally {
        fl.stopThread();
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Thank You !!!");
}
```

thanks for help.